# Event sourcing: Tracking each entity field changes in specific interval

Tags: sql, .net, database, cqrs, event-sourcing

I'm trying to figure out what could be the best solution for this use case:
there is a need to track each field changes in agreement entity. So when someone makes update for any field they must set when this is going to be applied (can set date in future or past). And later it should be possible to filter by some field's value in the past for specific date interval. So basically it's needed to have history of each field and apply correct value according to current date.
At first glance, it's possible to use event sourcing when entity is built from events on write side and for read side it could be used snapshots so on each new change for entity would be rebuild in SQL database table for quering operations.
Is there any simpler solution for this case?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ES could be an appropriate solution for your problem. You track all fields changes as separate events. And it would help if you create various read models according to your requirements.
If you need to store the history of each field change, you probably have a read model for this purpose and another for your last or per version snapshot of your read side entity.

**Noice**: You create your read models according to your current or future requirements. Maybe you need a new read model after 6 months, So you create another read model. BTW you can achieve this by using event sourcing.

Comment: But I face issue on Read side. Let's say I create event for the future, that means changes should not be made until it reaches that certain point of time. So if I keep read model in relational database I need to create sort of job that checks if read model should be updated because I will need that read model to return like a list. Using snapshots I can't create list because it is only for single aggregate to load (on write side I guess)

Comment: I don't mean "event for the future", Snapshots are for write-models. You don't need a job for updating read models. Every event that is published to the event stream, should projected by your projectors(read-model builders). You have only and only one event stream, But you can any kind of read models